# Flutter : Handling Error SocketException: Connection failed (OS Error: Network is unreachable, errno = 101)

Tags: flutter, dart

[image: No Connection]
I have a problem handling the error `SocketException: Connection failed (OS Error: Network is unreachable, errno = 101)  address = 192.168.43.159, port = 80`.

What I already did :

#### Setting Android Permission Internet.

My Reference [Making Network http error SocketException: Failed host lookup](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27883)

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

## Make function with `try catch` to handling this error

#### It's API function

```
Future loginMahasiswa(body) async {
    try {
      var apiRespon = await http.post('$baseURL/mahasiswa/login',
          body: body, headers: CrudComponent.headers);
      int statusCode = apiRespon.statusCode;
      if (statusCode == 200) {
        final apiResponJson = json.decode(apiRespon.body);
        print('Success Load Data Json ($apiResponJson)');
        return apiResponJson;
      } else {
        final apiResponJson = json.decode(apiRespon.body);
        print('fail Load Data Json $apiResponJson');
        return apiResponJson;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      return null;
    }
  }
```

#### It's Button Function

```
  void _loginMahasiswa() async {
    SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    try {
      final body = {"email": _txtEmail.text, "password": _txtPassword.text};
      var loginMahasiswa = await api.loginMahasiswa(body);
      String message = loginMahasiswa['message'];
      var dataUser = loginMahasiswa['data'];
      // String idUser = dataUser[0]['id_user'] ?? "null";
      if (loginMahasiswa['status'] == true) {
        setState(() {
          preferences.setString('token', dataUser[0]['username']);
          Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
              PageTransition(
                  type: PageTransitionType.rightToLeftWithFade,
                  child: HomePage()),
              (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
        });
      } else {
        print(message);
        _showSnackBar(context, message, Colors.red);
      }
    } on SocketException catch (_) {
      //throw ("No connection Internet");
       _showSnackBar(context, 'no connection', Colors.orange);
    }
  }
```

But my `Snackbar` does not show an error `no connection` if I click the button.

> I'm using a real device to run my app and I purposely turn off the hotspot to test my app not connected to the server.
>   [image: No Connection Image]

Comment: can you ping it via cmd or terminal?

Comment: @MyNameIs what should i ping ?

Comment: ping the ipaddress

Comment: From what I see its `NoSuchMethodError` exception that you are not handling

Comment: @SwiftingDuster Sorry ? So i'm not handling the `SocketException` ?

Comment: @MyNameIs My result ping ,`Ping statistics for 192.168.43.159:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms`

Comment: @ZeffryReynando this means your url is up and running

Answer (score 4):

1. Make sure you are online, you are connected to internet whether it is mobile or emulator
2. Make sure you have given internet permission in your app's `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`

   ```xml
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
   ```

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/> added but same issue

Answer (score 2):

For android device

**Step1:**

instead of using **localhost or 127.0.0.1** use **10.0.2.2**

**Step2:**

Add below tag into AndroidMainfest.xml.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

find the below image reference.

[image]